# Error when I try to run my WebService

Tags: iis, web-services

I installed my WebService (on Windows-XP), when I try to run, I get this error:

```
The server has encountered an error while loading an application during the processing of your request. Please refer to the event log for more detail information. Please contact the server administrator for assistance.
```

and in the log I see this:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source: W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID: 36
Date: 01/01/2001
Time: 01:13:24
User: N/A
Computer: WKS-007-102
Description:
The server failed to load application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT'.  The error was 'Class not registered
'. 
For additional information specific to this message please visit the Microsoft Online Support site located at: http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

How to fix it ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Launch command prompt and run the following commands.

> msdtc -install
>   net start msdtc

Then re-install IIS.